# MySQL Select Queries Explain

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a question regarding a select mysql query. Lets say that we have 2 tables

users: [ id, username ]
logs [ id, user_id, action ]

I want to selecr all users from table users with the count(`id`) of table logs based on user_id

I tried to do the following:

```
SELECT t1.*,count(t2.`id`) 
FROM `users` t1
LEFT JOIN `logs` t2 
ON  t1.id = t2.user_id;
```

But that only prints the users who have count logs > 0. I want to select all the users with the count of the logs.

Comment: You only have to add a grouping. GROUP BY t2.user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*,count(t2.`id`) 
FROM `users` t1
LEFT JOIN `logs` t2 
ON  t1.id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count(id) FROM `logs` WHERE `logs`.`id`=`id`) scount FROM `users`;
```

The count value you want will be in a field called `scount`.